# What is the difference between MatSidenav and the MatDrawer?

Tags: angular, angular-material

They can be found both on the same documentation page, but it seems to be the same. You know the difference from a functional perspective? What is the benefit using one over the other?

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Thanks first for reading.

Answer (score 41):

From the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview):

> The sidenav components are designed to add side content to a *fullscreen* app.

VS

> The drawer component is designed to add side content to a *small section* of your app.

<sup>^ Emphasis is mine</sup>

The difference between the two components is that the sidenav component should be used for a *global* drawer (like a [navigation drawer](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer)) while the drawer component should be used for content *specific to the small portion of your app* (such as allowing the user to [filter files](https://material.io/components/sheets-side)).

---

Additionally:

> They support almost all of the same features, but [drawers] do not support fixed positioning.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/15.1.x/src/material/sidenav/sidenav.ts), the sidenav components appear to all extend from the drawer components. Note specifically how the `MatSidenav` class has additional functionality for fixed positioning as mentioned above:

```
@Component({...})
export class MatSidenavContent extends MatDrawerContent {...}

@Component({...})
export class MatSidenav extends MatDrawer {
  /** Whether the sidenav is fixed in the viewport. */
  @Input()
  get fixedInViewport(): boolean {
    return this._fixedInViewport;
  }
  set fixedInViewport(value: BooleanInput) {
    this._fixedInViewport = coerceBooleanProperty(value);
  }
  private _fixedInViewport = false;

  /**
   * The gap between the top of the sidenav and the top of the viewport when the sidenav is in fixed
   * mode.
   */
  @Input()
  get fixedTopGap(): number {
    return this._fixedTopGap;
  }
  set fixedTopGap(value: NumberInput) {
    this._fixedTopGap = coerceNumberProperty(value);
  }
  private _fixedTopGap = 0;

  /**
   * The gap between the bottom of the sidenav and the bottom of the viewport when the sidenav is in
   * fixed mode.
   */
  @Input()
  get fixedBottomGap(): number {
    return this._fixedBottomGap;
  }
  set fixedBottomGap(value: NumberInput) {
    this._fixedBottomGap = coerceNumberProperty(value);
  }
  private _fixedBottomGap = 0;
}

@Component({...})
export class MatSidenavContainer extends MatDrawerContainer {...}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. Functionally what is the difference between the global concerned nav and a section on the screen? This documentation describes to different qualities associated with their application, but does not explain how they are functionally different. This answer doesn't help - unless this is pure semantics but then say so.